fail2ban blocks all ports when using iptables-multiport
I have an issue with fail2ban and iptables-multiport  which blocks all ports instead of the provided ones and I can't fnd why.
I have some web server listening on 443 and I have a honeypot listening on 1433 (MSSQL). What I want to achieve is when an IP comes to 1433, it gets blocked for 443 but still be serving by 1433 to waste its time.
So I have in /etc/fail2ban/jail.d/jail.local:
[banhoneypots]
enabled = true
filter = banhoneypots
# If some IP comes to Honeypots, ban it for http/https
action = iptables-multiport[name="BanHoneypots", port="http,https"]
logpath = /var/log/banhoneypots.log
maxretry = 1
bantime = 432000

And in /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/banhoneypots.conf:
# BanHoneypots filter
[Definition]
failregex =
ignoreregex =

I can test this from another device in my lab; everything is OK with 443,1433 when its IP is not in banhoneypots but when I insert its IP in banhoneypots, it gets blocked for 443 (which is expected) but for 1433 (and probably all others) as well.
I probably missed something but I can find out.
Addition:
I'm no fail2ban nor iptables expert but does that make sense:
(IP 192.168.0.10 has been sent to jail banhoneypots)
sudo iptables --list -n
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
f2b-BanHoneypots  tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 80,443
...
Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
f2b-BanHoneypots  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
...

Chain f2b-BanHoneypots (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
REJECT     all  --  192.168.0.10         0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
...
Chain f2b-banslow (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
REJECT     all  --  192.168.0.10         0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Anyone can help?
Thanks,
Jean

You could do all of these only with iptables. Here is an overview of how this could be achieved using iptables and ipset:
ipset create protected_zone hash:ip
ipset create block_src hash:ip 
iptables -N HTTPCONTROL

iptables -I FORWARD -m set --match-set protected_zone dst -p tcp --dport 1443 -m set --add-set block_src src -j HTTPCONTROL
iptables -I HTTPCONTROL -m set --match-set protected_zone dst -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j DROP

First, you create a zone ipset including your public ip address(es), then a block_src ipset to store those that have visited your protected zone's port 1443.
Then, you add the source ip addresses of the packets that are destined for your protected zone's port 1443, then jump to another custom chain HTTPCONTROL.
On this custom chain, we block the block_src ipset's requests towards our protected zone's HTTP/S ports.
I hope this solution helps.

Thanks for your suggestion venator. At this momet, I prefer to stay with fail2ban as it will automatically unban the IP after a while.

'ipset create block_src hash:ip timeout 3600'. You could do this using ipsets as well. The timeout is calculated as seconds and in this case, it would delete the ip addresses that are added to this ipset after 3600 seconds (1 hour). But at the end, its your decision of course. Just wanted to say it is doable using ipsets & iptables as well.

Interesting. I would have to redesign my own dev to call ipset (typically "ipset add block_src ") instead of fail2ban-client but that looks feasible. Need to check against potential other dependencies on fail2ban but defiitively something to look at. Thanks!
